# Activate form button when open page with it

Tags: forms, button, scripting

I have form button "but1" on one page, it has some function but i need to activate this button not personally, but automatically when page is open (and if it possible, activate repeatedly 10 times with 5s delay, or looping)

i tried something like this:

```
function activateButton() {
var button = this.getField("But1")
button.buttonSetState(1)
}

setTimeout(activateButton, 5000)
```

but this not work.